# How many rings have four elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There are at least three mutually non-isomorphic rings with $4$ elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279388/there-are-at-least-three-mutually-non-isomorphic-rings-with-4-elements)

How can I prove how many rings are commutative, unitary with 4 elements?

(obviously isomorphism doesn't matter)
I don't know it is something about quaternions.
It seems trivial but I don't know.

Comment: I think that this question is essentially a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/279388/11619) of another recent question. May be not an exact duplicate, but the answers in the linked question cover it all IMHO.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Thus, voting to close as such.

Comment: +1 to Martin's answer. The exact same list was constructed in the discussion of the linked question, which is why I think this is *essentially* duplicate. Others may take a different view, and that discussion is better moved to meta. Actually the meta-thread on abstract duplicates probably covers this.