# Give an example of a non-commutative ring of order $4?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a non-commutative ring of order $4?$

I found an example as follows: Let $R=\{0,a,b,c\}$ with a binary operation + defined on it.

The multiplication table is given by:

[image]

Does this suffice as an example? Or do we need to define what the operation $+$ looks like explicitly? Precisely, do I need to write out an addition table just like the multiplication table above?

Comment: If you want to define a ring, yes, you also need to define what + means in it. And, importantly, you need to make sure that + and * are distributive. (i.e. (x+y)*z = x*z + y*z and x*(y+z) = x*y + x*z; if the ring is not commutative, those are not equivalent)

Comment: @Cecilia Can you please help me define the operation of $+$ then?

Comment: As info: By your definition of ring, does your multiplication need to have a unit element?

Comment: @Cecilia No, not necessarily.

Comment: Recall that the addition of a ring forms an abelian group. There are only $2$ abelian groups of order $4$, and the cyclic group will always make your multiplication commutative. (Because of distributitvity). So there is only one possible way left the addition can work; then you'll have to adapt your multiplication to that addition.

Comment: The smallest *ring* (as opposed to a *rng* like here) [has order eight](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/618111/11619).