# Ring structure on a ring of order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was solving this question - "How many non-isomorphic rings are there of order 4 elements?"

I know there are two groups of order $4$, i.e., $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ (Characteristic $2$) and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (Characteristic $4$). With help from [Non isomorphic rings of order 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213201/non-isomorphic-rings-of-order-4), I got that there are $3$ non-isomorphic ring structures on $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. I also know that the there are only $4$ non-isomorphic rings of order $4$. Thus there is only $1$ non-isomorphic ring structure possible on $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Let $R=\{0,1,a,b\}$ ( $\cong \mathbb{Z}_4$ as a group) and characteristic of $R$ is $4$. Note $1+1=a$ and $b=1+a$. Then $b^2=(1+a)^2=1+a^2+2a=1+a^2$ and $ab=a(1+a)=a+a^2$ and $ab=ba$.

Then let us study these possible cases:

**Case $a^2=0$.** Then $b^2=1$ and $ab=a$

**Case $a^2=1$.** Then $b^2=a$ and $ab=b$

**Case $a^2=a$.** Then $b^2=b$ and $ab=0$

**Case $a^2=b$.** Then $b^2=0$ and $ab=1$

Now Case $a^2=0$ is the usual ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}_4$. And the case $a^2=b$ is not valid since $ab=1$ implies $ab^2=b$, since $b^2=0$ this implies $b=0$. I don't know how to eliminate the cases $a^2=1$ and $a^2=a$.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: With this kind of things, it's useful to take not of what you are and what you aren't using. So far in your case study I haven't seen you use the additive structure of a ring.

Comment: @take008 Thanks, I got it. Since $2b=a$, then $2ab=a^2$ and since $2a=0$ this implies $a^2=0$. Thus only first case is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to go to all this trouble. Notice that
$$a^2=(1+1)(1+1)=1+1+1+1=0$$
$$b^2=(1+1+1)(1+1+1)=9\cdot 1=1$$
$$ab=6\cdot 1=a$$