# The ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

Let  $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2)$ be the ring of Gaussian Integers and $I=(2)$ be the ideal generated by $2$. Then $I=\{2(x+yi) | x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Therefore the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2)$ are the cosets $a+bi +I$.

Here we have $4$ cases depending on whether $a, b$ are even or odd integers and therefore we have $4$ cosets $I, 1+I, i+I$ and $1+i+I$. Now we have that $ord(1+I)=2$ since $1+I + 1+I =2+I =I$. Similarly we have that $ord(i+I)=2$ and $ord(1+i+I)=2$ and therefore $(\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2),+)\simeq(\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2},+)$.

Now what about $(\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2),\cdot)$? We know that it not a field because it contains zero divisors. Indeed $(1+i+I)(1+i+I)=I$. So we know it is commutative ring with identity. But can we find if it is isomorphic to a familiar ring?

Comment: When you wrote $(\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2),\cdot)$, did you mean $(\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2),+,\cdot)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2+1 \rangle$ we get $$\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2+1,2 \rangle = \mathbb{F}_2[X]/\langle X^2+1 \rangle = \mathbb{F}_2[X]/\langle (X+1)^2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{F}_2[Y]/\langle Y^2 \rangle.$$
This is the ring of [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) over $\mathbb{F}_2$. It is one of the $4$ rings with $4$ elements (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279388/)).

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by local? Also we know that if we have a group with 4 elements then it's either $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ or the Klein group. Is there a similar classification for rings with 4 elements?

Comment: Please check my edit. :)

Comment: Okay, I just saw the edit, thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring (all basic definitions can be found at Wikipedia)

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf.  recent updates to site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: It was marked as a duplicate after my answer ...