Three non-isomorphic rings whose additive group is the Klein four-group.
I was looking at OEIS sequence A037291, which gives the number of rings with identity that have $n$ elements. That page linked me to a website written by C. Noebauer which claims that there are three non-isomorphic rings with identity that have an underlying additive group that is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^2$.
One of them is the direct product of rings $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with the usual (componentwise) multiplication:
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  \times_1 & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\
  (0,1)    & (0,1) & (0,0) & (0,1) \\
  (1,0)    & (0,0) & (1,0) & (1,0) \\
  (1,1)    & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\
\end{array}
Another is given by the field $\mathbb{F}_4$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of the polynomial $x^2 + x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ so that $\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1$. Then $\mathbb{F}_4 = \{0, 1, \alpha, 1 + \alpha\}$, and we can consider the ring isomorphism which sends $1 \mapsto (1,0)$ and $\alpha \mapsto (0,1)$. This gives us the multiplication table
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  \times_2 & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\
  (0,1)    & (1,1) & (0,1) & (1,0) \\
  (1,0)    & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\
  (1,1)    & (1,0) & (1,1) & (0,1) \\
\end{array}
What is the third such ring? And does it arise in any kind of natural setting?

More-or-less a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279388/there-are-at-least-three-mutually-non-isomorphic-rings-with-4-elements and see also several links at that question to other questions.

So we have a ring with four elements $\{0,1,x,1+x\}$ such that the sum of every element with itself is $0$. Then we can determine the multiplication from $x^2$ alone because $x(1+x)=(1+x)x = x+x^2$ and $(1+x)^2 = 1 + x + x + x^2 = 1 + x^2$.
What is $x^2$? We have four possibilities.

$x^2 = 0$ implies $x(1+x) = (1+x)x = x + x^2 = x$ and $(1+x)^2 = 1+x^2=1$

$x^2 = 1$ implies $x(1+x)=(1+x)x = x+x^2 = 1+x$ and $(1+x)^2 = 1+x^2 = 0$. So this is really isomorphic to the previous case by sending $x \mapsto 1+x$.

$x^2 = x$ implies $x(1+x) = x + x^2 = x + x = 0$ and $(1+x)^2 = 1 + x^2 = 1+x$. This is $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$.

$x^2 = 1+x$ implies $x(1+x)=(1+x)x = x + x^2 = 1 + x + x = 1$ and $(1+x)^2 = 1 + x^2 = 1 + 1 + x = x$. This is $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$.


So the missing ring is one in which there is an element squaring to zero, cases 1 and 2 above. It arises as the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle 2, x^2 \rangle = \mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$.
Interesting to note that all of these are commutative.

Abstract explanation why they have to be commutative (which is basically equivalent to your point about $x^2$ determining everything):  they're all generated by a single element as $\mathbb F_2$-algebras, and powers of a given element always commute.

So the missing ring is to $\mathbb F_2$ what dual numbers are to $\mathbb R$?
